# Laravel login attempt works locally but not on on AWS ECS Load Balancer

Tags: laravel

My login controller is as shown below.
My setup is a ECS cluster with load balancers. The whole things works fine locally using docker-comopse up but on my server I get a 200 response but when I get to if the user is auth'ed it returns a false.

I am thinking it could be my setup related, any ideas at all?

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password')), true)) {
            return response()->json([
                'user' => $user,
            ]);
        }
        ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        ]);
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Unauthorized",
        ], 401);

    }
```

Comment: `$user` is undefined btw

Comment: Was a typo sorry